# React Native the correct Rating star is not displayed

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, ratingbar

I dont know why but my Rating stars are not updated even though I have called the method. This is my sample code:

```
import { Rating } from 'react-native-elements-master';

componentDidMount() {

return this.mediavoti()

}
```

My costructor:

```
  constructor(props) {

super(props);

this.state = {

  Mediaevento: '2'
}
}
```

and this is my method:

```
mediavoti() {   

  return fetch('url', 
{
method: 'POST',
headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
body: JSON.stringify({

  Idevento: this.props.navigation.state.params.TiPasso_Idevento,

})

}).then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
  this.setState({

    Mediaevento: responseJson[0].Media

  }, function () {

  });

}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
 }
```

This is my Rating render component:

```
 <Rating

      type="star"
      fractions={1}

      startingValue={parseFloat(this.state.Mediaevento)}
      imageSize={40}
      onFinishRating={this.voto}
       showRating
      style={{ paddingVertical: 10 }} />
```

I dont know why but it always sees that the state.mediaevento value is 2. But if I use console.log in mediavoti() method I can see that the state is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.
`componentWillMount() {
    return this.mediavoti()
    }`

Instead of componentDidMount()

Comment: Can you try this:---------
this.setState({
    Mediaevento: responseJson[0].Media
  }, () => {
       this.forceUpdate();
  });

Comment: Are you getting correct data from ----
Mediaevento: responseJson[0].Media

Comment: yes, if I do "console.log(this.state.Mediaevento)" before `}).catch((error)` I can see my json response